# How to fectch data from table in cakephp

Tags: mysql, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

Hi i have one table in my database which has list of states and i want to fetch this data from the table but my query is not executing properly it gives me some error

```
<?php
                require_once('../Config/database.php');
                $result1=$this->Signup->query("SELECT * FROM states");

 //echo $popular;
 while($post = mysql_fetch_array($result1))

{ ?>

                <table width="380">
                          <tr>
                            <td class="table_txt"><a class="thickbox tn" href="demo.php?state_name=<?php echo $post['state_name']?>&state_id=<?php echo $post['state_id']?>&height=430&height=430&width=700&inlineId=myOnPageContent"><?php echo $post['state_name']?></a></td>

                          </tr>
                    </table>
                    <?php   } 
?>
```

But it gives me error
Warning (512): Method SignupHelper::query does not exist [CORE\Cake\View\Helper.php, line 192
Warning (2): mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given

Comment: You obviously haven’t bothered to read the [CakePHP documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/index.html), otherwise you wouldn’t be running **raw** SQL queries, *in a view*. If you can’t be bothered to read documentation, weren’t not going to be bothered to answer your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read [the documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html) first.

It seems you are trying to get the states, inside the View, with a query.
You need to separate the view from the model.

Create a `State` model.

Use something like this in your controller:

```
$this->loadModel('State');
$states = $this->State->find('list'); // this will create a key => value array with the IDs and names
$this->set('states', $states);
```

In your view, use

```
<table width="380">
 <tr>
    <?php foreach ($states as $stateId => $stateName) {
    <td class="table_txt"><a class="thickbox tn" href="demo.php?state_name=<?php echo $stateName?>&state_id=<?php echo $stateId?>&height=430&height=430&width=700&inlineId=myOnPageContent"><?php echo $stateName ?>></a></td>
    <?php } ?>
</tr>
```

You might still need some changes, but this is the main idea.

Comment: i have created the State model and i have used your code in controller and in virew page but it gives me this error Call to a member function find() on a non-object C:\wamp\www\test\app\Controller\SignupsController.php

Comment: I added `$this->loadModel('State');` in the answer and changed to `$this->State->find...`

Comment: it's worked perfectly but i have one doubt that if i need to fetch the data from 5 table then i need to create the 5model means individual model for every table or there is any other way to do this

Comment: Each table should have its own model. This is how you should work. Later on, when you add more functions related to one of the tables/models, it will be easier